# Need to install all packages at once for a solution in vs 2015 using nuget

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Install multiple packages at once using some nuget commands.

In my solution I have much projects and it takes a lot of time to install each package via gui, need help to install all of those with a single command.

Answer (score 1):

The Update-Package command will install and update all packages in all projects:

http://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Manager-Console-PowerShell-Reference#update-package

You can provide additional attributes into this command and it will update packages appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a powershell script to do it. ie. something like:

```
Install-Package package1 -ProjectName project
Install-Package package2 -ProjectName project
Install-Package package3 -ProjectName project
```

Then you could just right-click on the script in Windows explorer and run it.